# Position a chart top left

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am a newbie using d3 and javascript, but have managed to cobble together some code (using borrowed code from online examples) to create a simple column chart with different colours indicating the status of a variable. Everything works well except that the chart will not position at the top left of the canvas despite adjusting the margin.top or margin.left to small values. If I adjust the browser window to portrait, the chart aligns left but with white significant amounts of white space above it. If I adjust the browser window to landscape the chart aligns to the top but with significant amounts of white space to the left of it.  Can someone please advise as to where I have gone wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>


.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
</style>

<svg class="chart"></svg>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var data = [
    {
        "status": "Low",
        "value": "20",
        "color": "red"
    },
    {
        "status": "Marginal",
        "value": "10",
        "color": "orange"
    },
    {
        "status": "High",
        "value": "70",
        "color": "green"
    }
];

var margin = {top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 30},
    width = 200 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
.rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left")
.ticks(10);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.status; }));
y.domain([0, 100]);


svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.call(yAxis)
.append("text")
.attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
.attr("y", 6)
.attr("dy", ".71em")
.style("text-anchor", "end")
.text("Probability");

svg.selectAll(".bar")
.data(data)
.enter().append("rect")
.attr("class", "bar")
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.status); })
.attr("width", x.rangeBand())
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
.attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })

.style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; });

function type(d) {
    d.frequency = +d.frequency;
    return d;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you have an `<svg class="chart">` element, but your code appends yet another `<svg>` element to the page after that one, and the first one takes some space